# How can I get the *UN*matched criteria for a Django .filter(something__in=some_set) query?

Tags: python, django

Not infrequently, I find myself with a set of identifiers and want to retrieve all the objects in a table that match any of the identifiers, but *also* want to see all the identifiers that didn't have any matched objects in the database.

The way I do this now is:

```
some_ids = ("a", "b", "c")
matched_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(my_key__in=some_ids)
caught_ids = set()
for obj in matched_objects:
    caught_ids.add(obj.my_key)
unmatched_ids = set(some_ids) - caught_ids
```

This feels very verbose. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question get distict values for your `my_key` field

```
caught_ids = matched_objects.values_list('my_key').distinct()
```

then get `unmatched_ids` just like you did before.

```
unmatched_ids = set(some_ids) - set(caught_ids)
```

Your code would look like this:

```
some_ids = ("a", "b", "c")
matched_objects = MyModel.objects.filter(my_key__in=some_ids)
caught_ids = matched_objects.values_list('my_key').distinct()
unmatched_ids = set(some_ids) - set(caught_ids)
```

Comment: And make another query?

Comment: No other query is needed.

Comment: He wants both the models matching the id list and the list of ids that didn't match. Your code doesn't get the first part, hence the need for a second query

Comment: It looks like your query as written will do a SELECT DISTINCT my_key on the whole table? That seems inefficient since I only care about which of my existing some_id's keys don't have a match. You could maybe do .values_list('my_key').distinct() on the matched_objects QuerySet to avoid the second query? Or is there a reason your query automatically limits its scope?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get a list of keys that match your IDs

some_ids = set(some_ids)
keys = set(MyModel.objects.filter(my_key__in = some_ids).values_list('my_key',flat=True))
```

Presumably `keys` will contain all those IDs that existed in `some_ids`. Now we can use typical set operations to identify those elements that match or don't match. There are a number of examples here (http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) but from your comment, it sounds like you want:

```
unmatched = some_ids not in keys
```

Comment: I think this gets existing models that don't match one of my id's. What I want is my id's that don't match an existing model.

Comment: I think this now has the same issue as the other answer that it will do a SELECT DISTINCT on the entire table, which seems inefficient. If I have 10 id's, 7 of them will have matches, and there are 1 million objects in the database, it seems almost certainly better to filter in some way.

Comment: This doesn't select distinct, this selects all IDs. Which is what you'd have to do either way to compare. It's essentially the same as doing `SELECT my_key from MyModel`. The rest is done with set mechanics which tend to be pretty fast.

Comment: My mistake on the distinct, but still it intuitively seems like asking the DB to select and return a million rows through the wire is going to take longer than asking it to do a comparison of just the relevant rows either in the DB or locally.

Comment: If your DB is that big, you should probably be running a raw query directly on the DB rather than using the abstraction layer.

Comment: It seems like selecting every row of a database of any size for a query like this has to be inefficient relative to selecting just what you need...

Comment: I suppose since you're just looking for those that don't match `some_ids` you could pull those that do match and then use set properties to compare.